# Inverse of a $T^{1/2}$ operator provided $T$ is positive and invertible

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a quick question if I have that my operator $T$ is positive ie $(x,Tx) \geq c||x||$ for $c>0$ and all $x$. Then by a theorem from  Functional analysis by Riesz and Nagy we have that there exists a unique positive operator $A$ such that $A^2= T$ and we can call $A= T^{1/2}$. My question is if we know that $T$ is invertible can we claim that $T^{1/2}$ is also invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is as stated with inverse $T^{-1}$. The unique square root $A$ of $T$ commutes with $T$ and with $T^{-1}$ because $T^{-1}$ commutes with $T$. Furthermore,
$$
                     A^2T^{-1}=T^{-1}A^2 = I \\
                     A(AT^{-1})=(AT^{-1})A=I
$$
Therefore $A$ is invertible with inverse $AT^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Try assuming that $T^{1/2}$ is not invertible and see where that leads you.